# Trajectory Tree

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm looking to plot something similar to this in R.  Can this be this be done with ggplot or some other package?

[image: Trajectory Tree]

Found on the following blog:

http://intelligenttradingtech.blogspot.com/2011/07/pattern-recognition-forward-boxplot.html

Comment: Only thing that I can think of so far is a custom tree using party, but that seems over complicated.

Comment: Paul Murrell has some papers on the subject such as [Drawing Diagrams with R](http://www.stat.auckland.ac.nz/~paul/R/Diagram/diagram.pdf)

Comment: -1 - any chance of a fuller specification of what these trees might look like? Your question is only going to spawn more questions...

Comment: @davewolfs, would it be possible for you to respond to Spacedman comment? (apparently other people are up-voting his comment)

Comment: Not sure I fully understand what @Spacedman would like me to add.

Comment: Saying "something similar to this" isn't a very good description of the problem. Describe the inputs and the outputs - and give examples when possible. Explain how the inputs affect the outputs. Do you only ever want the same branching structure, or could there be more branches? Why are some arrows shorter than others - does the length represent something? What does 27/52*.0159 mean? Where do those numbers come from? etc etc.

Comment: @Spacedman, thank you for your constructive response to Davewolfs comment.

Comment: @Davewolfs, did you see Spacedman's great feedback?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is how to construct the graph using `ggplot2`.

[image]

I constructed the data manually, by specifying the coordinates of each line start and end position. An improvement would obviously be to automate this using an algorithm. Since this wasn't the question, I didn't attempt to solve this too.

Create the data:

```
arrowdata <- c(
  0, 0, 1, 0,
  1, 1, 2, 1,
  1, -1, 2, -1,
  2, 1.5, 3, 1.5,
  2, 0.5, 3, 0.5
)

linesdata <- c(
  1, 0, 1, 1,
  1, 0, 1, -1,
  2, 1, 2, 1.5,
  2, 1, 2, 0.5
)

labeldata <- data.frame(
  x = c(0.5, 1.5, 2.5),
  y = c(0, 1, 1.5),
  labels=c("Label 1", "Label2", "Label 3")
)

adat <- as.data.frame(matrix(arrowdata, ncol=4, byrow=TRUE))
ldat <- as.data.frame(matrix(linesdata, ncol=4, byrow=TRUE))
```

Load the `ggplot2` and `grid` packages, then plot:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(grid) # For arrow() function
ggplot() + 
  geom_segment(
    data=adat, 
    aes(x=V1, y=V2, xend=V3, yend=V4),
    arrow=arrow(length = unit(0.05, "npc"), type="closed"),
    col="blue"
  ) +
  geom_segment(
    data=ldat, 
    aes(x=V1, y=V2, xend=V3, yend=V4),
    col="blue"
  ) +
  geom_text(data=labeldata, aes(x, y, label=labels), 
    size=8, vjust=-0.2, col="blue"
  ) +
  theme_bw() +
  opts(
    axis.text.x=theme_blank(),
    axis.text.y=theme_blank(),
    axis.ticks=theme_blank(),
    axis.title.x=theme_blank(),
    axis.title.y=theme_blank(),
    panel.grid.major=theme_blank(),
    panel.border=theme_blank()
  ) +
coord_cartesian(ylim=c(-1.5, 2)) # Create some additional space for labels
```

Answer (score 1):

You might find something at http://addictedtor.free.fr/graphiques/ .   There's an amazing variety of graphs and charts there.  Now, it's easy enough to write a little code using the base `plot` and `graphics::arrow` functions that will draw lines between the vertices.  E.g.,

```
arrows(0,1,0,0) 
lines(c(1,1),c(-.5,.5)) 
arrows(1,2,.5,.5)
```

and so on.  Do you have a requirement to size or place the branches based on data, or is this a purely qualitative tree?